# JavaScript BigInt ceil() function

Tags: javascript, bigint, ceil

Given that Math.ceil(1/3) yields 1, how do I get that 1 (or 1n) from BigInt input values of 1n and 3n?
Obviously Math.ceil(Number(1n)/Number(3n)) would work but some bigints might be too big for that approach.

Comment: `BigInt` only deals with integers. There are no fractions, so no need for the `ceil()` function.

Comment: @JaromandaX That's my point. It doesn't return a fraction, so you can't get the ceiling of it.

Comment: @Barmar - ahh, I see what you're saying now :p sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple function

*Note: the `.toString()` is ONLY so the console output is shown here*

```js
const ceilN = (n, d) => n / d + (n % d ? 1n : 0n)

console.log(ceilN(120n, 3n).toString()); // 40
console.log(ceilN(121n, 3n).toString()); // 41
console.log(ceilN(122n, 3n).toString()); // 41
console.log(ceilN(123n, 3n).toString()); // 41
```

Comment: Thanks. To make it work with signed inputs I believe it needs to be +(n%d>0n?1n:0n)

Comment: yeah, I hate modulo on negatives :p

Comment: For positive inputs, this can be made more efficient: `(n, d) => (n + d - 1n) / d`; that approach gets a bit messy though if it needs to handle negative inputs as well.